# "Like" button connecting with specific articles on my website

Tags: button, facebook-like

I am having an issue with my website I just can not seem to solve.  I do not understand how I can get my website to understand how to "like" specific articles that are written on it.  Also, whenever I do hit the "like" button it in turn chooses to "like" the entire page and designates the "facebook" logo as being the icon of the website.  I hope I explained this accurately.  Feel free to take a peek at my website @ www.diehardsportsfan.com  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you've downloaded some code and installed it without knowing what it does. I'm extremely reluctant to go to your website and discover whatever else may be lurking there.

Comment: Obscure, poke fun at me later...right now HELP!!  LoL

Comment: I'm not poking fun at you, I'm pointing out that you have put code into your website that you don't understand. First step is to take it out. Next step is to understand what it does. When you know what it does, or at least have narrowed it down to a small section that you don't understand, post the offending code here.

Comment: Obscure...how do you get a website to understand/"like" specific articles?  That is the question and the issue.

Comment: You need to give the like button a URI for your specific article, rather than your entire website. But if the code is setting your website's icon to facebook's icon, something strange is going on.

Comment: Obscure, This may come off as a silly question to you but I cut and paste the entire document from "Word" to "Dreamweaver."  Is this not the process of which I should be inserting my documents?  Is there another?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the [Facebook like button code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). If you aren't, you should probably start with the official Facebook stuff. Avoid trusting random social media code that you find. Could be spammy/scammy.

I put "http://w3c.org" into the URL to like box, and go the following code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://w3c.org" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

There is another block to load the JavaScript FacebookSDK, so don't forget that.

Anyway, you can see that the URL I gave was pasted into data-href.

So if you had articles at w3c.org identified by `#articleXXXX` where `XXXX` is a number, you would just replace the data-href with the appropriate link to your article like this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://w3c.org#4242" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Each article will need its own button, and each button instance should be linked to the permalink for its corresponding article.

Comment: Thanks Obscure.  I'm new to coding so some things are relatively brand new.  I believe my issue stems my minimal understanding and management of the Facebook Developers Site.  Working on it.